# How can I use jQuery to pull the ids from a multiple collection select?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, collections, simple-form

I'm a hobbyist on my first project.  If I've got this simpleform collection:

```
<%= f.input :events, collection: @organizer.events.order(:start_time).reverse, label_method: :event_name_and_date, input_html: {multiple: true, id: "event_select"} %>
```

How can I pull the event.id from the selected events, so I can dynamically update the rest of the ensuing form with the individual ids?   Currently, if I grab the value of the collection, all the ids are combined in one long string.  I don't know how to break them up and store them.

For example, I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#event_select').on('change', function(){
        var grab_events = $('#event_select').val();
        $('#show_events').html(grab_events);    
    })
  });

</script>
```

But that just shows a string of all the ids, uselessly.   Ids 43, 65, 32, and 8 come out as '4365328'

Comment: `grab_event` is an array, you can loop it or do something like: `.html(grab_events.map(i =>  $(\`<div>${i}</div>\`)))`

Comment: Thanks.   I've updated the question to clarify - all the ids of the highlighted events in the collection come out as one long string.   I don't know how to break them up.

Comment: AH, ok cool.   I would like to use the ids later on in the form as paramethers for certain fields.

Comment: I was working on a pretty complex formula to create an array from the returned string of numbers lol.  I appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grab_events` is an array. When using `.html()`, jQuery is inserting each element individually by looping, without invoking `toString()`. since newlines aren't relevant, looks like a long string. One solution is call `toString()` manually, or wrap the items in a block element.

Of course, being an array you can do whatever you want with it later.

```js
$('#event_select').on('change', function() {
  var grab_events = $('#event_select').val();

  // Inserting array, resulting in one long string
  $('#show_events').html(grab_events);
  // Separate with commas
  $('#show_events2').html(grab_events.toString());
  // Create a div for each element
  $('#show_events3').html(grab_events.map(i => $(`<div>${i}</div>`)));

  grab_events.forEach(i => {
    // Whatever you want to do
  });
})
```

```css
#show_events {
  background-color: red;
}

#show_events2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#show_events3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="event_select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="11">item 1</option>
  <option value="24">item 2</option>
  <option value="43">item 3</option>
  <option value="4">item 4</option>
  <option value="35">item 5</option>
  <option value="16">item 6</option>
</select>
<div id="show_events"></div>
<div id="show_events2"></div>
<div id="show_events3"></div>
```